# Spark matrix multiplication code takes a lot of time to execute

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple PySpark environment set up using `findspark.init()` on Spyder and I'm running the code on localhost. I am confused as to how can simple matrix multiplication take hours and hours of time using BlockMatrix in Spark, whereas the same code takes a few mins to run on numpy.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cross_validation as cv
import itertools
import random
import findspark
import time
start=time.time()

findspark.init()

from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('myapp')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *

def as_block_matrix(rdd, rowsPerBlock=1024, colsPerBlock=1024):
    return IndexedRowMatrix(
        rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda xi: IndexedRow(xi[1], xi[0]))
    ).toBlockMatrix(rowsPerBlock, colsPerBlock)

def prediction(P,Q):
#    np.r_[ pp,np.zeros(len(pp)) ].reshape(2,20)
    Pn=np.r_[ P,np.zeros(len(P)),np.zeros(len(P)),np.zeros(len(P)),np.zeros(len(P)) ].reshape(5,len(P))
    Qn=np.r_[ Q,np.zeros(len(Q)),np.zeros(len(Q)),np.zeros(len(Q)),np.zeros(len(Q)) ].reshape(5,len(Q))
    A = Pn[:1]
    B = Qn[:1].T
    distP = sc.parallelize(A)
    distQ = sc.parallelize(B)
    mat=as_block_matrix(distP).multiply(as_block_matrix(distQ))
    blocksRDD = mat.blocks
    m=(list(blocksRDD.collect())[0][1])
    #print(m)
    return m.toArray()[0,0]

for epoch in range(1):
    for u, i in zip(users,items):
        e = R[u, i] - prediction(P[:,u],Q[:,i])
```

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing the size of your matrices makes it more difficult to answer this question, but if you are working with high dimensional sparse matrices, one possible issue is inherent to the way pyspark does matrix multiplication. In order to multiply sparse matrices, pyspark converts the sparse matrices to dense matrices. This is noted in the documentation:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix.multiply

which states that:

> multiply(other) Left multiplies this BlockMatrix by other, another BlockMatrix. The colsPerBlock of this matrix must equal the rowsPerBlock of other. If other contains any SparseMatrix blocks, they will have to be converted to DenseMatrix blocks. The output BlockMatrix will only consist of DenseMatrix blocks. This may cause some performance issues until support for multiplying two sparse matrices is added.

As far as I know, there isn't a good work around for this if you intend to use the built in matrix data types. One way to fix is to abandon the matrix datatypes and hand roll your own matrix multiplication using rdd or dataframe join operations. For example, if you can use dataframes, the following has been tested and works fairly well at scale:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

def multiply_df_matrices(A,B):
    return A.join(B,A['column']==B['row'])\
            .groupBy(A['row'],B['column'])\
            .agg(sum(A['value']*B['value']).alias('value'))
```

You can do something similar by joining two rdds.